# Generar PDF de un post en Django

Tags: python, django, pdf

Tengo un Blog en wordpress y lo estoy migrando Django, tengo un plugins  instalado en wordpress que permite generar un PDF de un post y deseo pasar esa funcionalidad a Django.

Después de mucho buscar y varias pruebas, utilizo `django-wkhtmltopdf` para generar el PDF, pero no consigo generarlo de forma correcta.

Tengo integrado CKeditor para generar el contenido de los post que se almacena en el campo `body`

```
#models.py
from ckeditor.fields import RichTextField
from ckeditor_uploader.fields import RichTextUploadingField

class Entry(models.Model):

    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    body = RichTextUploadingField()
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    .....
```

Utilizo  `PDFTemplateResponse` en un vista CBV para la generación del PDF

```
#views.py
class MyPDFView(DetailView):
model = Entry
template = 'pdf_export.html'
context = {'titulo': 'Hola prueba'}

def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    self.context['entry'] = self.get_object()

    response=PDFTemplateResponse(request=request,
                                 template=self.template,
                                 filename ="postPDF.pdf",
                                 context=self.context,
                                 show_content_in_browser=True,
                                 cmd_options={'margin-top': 50,}
                                 )
    return response
```

Para llamar a la vista utilizo la siguiente urls

```
url(r'^pdf/(?P<slug>\S+)$', views.MyPDFView.as_view(), name='pagina_detalle'),
```

Cuando genera un PDF lo hago con la siguiente plantilla.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<body>
    <h1> {{ titulo }}</h1>
    <p>{{ entry.title }}</p>
    <br/>
    <p>{{entry.body}}</p>
</body>
```

Por último , he creado un enlace en cada post para que genere el PDF , que llama a la url correspondiente.

```
<i><u><h5><a href="{% url "pagina_detalle"  slug=object.slug %}"> Generar PDF de {{object.title}}</a></h5></u></i>
```

Todo esto me genera un pdf con título , título del post, `title`, y el contenido ,`body`.

El problema es con  el campo `body`, muestra  todo el código HTML que  genera CKeditor, tampoco muestra las imágenes de un post.

¿Como puedo generar un PDF correctamente?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega el filtro `safe` a `entry.body` y el filtro `striptags` a `entry.title` y prueba de nuevo.

Comment: Gracias, funciona, muestra el PDF de forma correcta